# i need to receive some data from user, and want to get it into a loop (to save code lines)

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I try to do some kind of a loop, to shorten a code. in general I need to take some data (text sentences) that a user enter, and then save it into a text file. its need to be in this order:

```
Title = ["This is the title"];
Subtitle = ["This is the Subtitle"];
bullet1 = ["111"];
bullet2 = ["2222"];
bullet3 = ["3333"];
```

The user have an option to add more bullets (its start from 1).

So i want to make a loop and to be able to enter all the bullets the user enter into a text file. my code of this part is:

```
var createBullet = document.getElementById('createBullet'),
        titleBullet = document.getElementById('titleBullet'),
        subtitleBullet = document.getElementById('subtitleBullet');
    var bullet = [];
    var text = "Title = [";
    var text2 = "];";
    var text3 = text + titleBullet.value + text2;
    var y;
    createBullet.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (y = 1; y <= x; y++){
          bullet[y] = document.getElementById(y + 'Bullet');
          var link = document.getElementById('downloadBullet');
          link.href = maketextFileBullet( text3 +=

              '\nbullet' + [y] + ' = ["' + bullet[y].value + '"];'
        )};
      link.style.display = 'block';

    }, false);
```

If I use the += in line 13 (and in general this code exactly) so i get:

```
Title = [];
bullet1 = ["111"];
bullet2 = ["222"];
```

When I use only 2 bullets. but in title it not getting what the user wrote, which saved on titleBullet

If I change line 13 to be like this:

```
 link.href = maketextFileBullet( text + titleBullet.value + text2 +
```

The results will be like this:

```
Title = [eran];
bullet2 = ["222"];
```

It's missing bullet1.

Hope you can help me. thanks!

Comment: You might think you're making sense, but your question is not a [mcve]. Please [edit] your question and post all relevant code so that the problem can be reproduced. Some things that would help are the accompanying HTML, and the function definition for `maketextFileBullet()`.

Comment: Or you can use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) OR [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) to create a demo file. so anyone can make change in your code & resolve your problem.

Comment: i fixed the problem i had ,i just had to change a position of the var text to be after the createBullet.addEventListener function and not before it.  thanks!!